# Python Selenium Export data in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to export the result of the web scraping using Selenium, but it only exports the first data of my lists, and I need it to export all the data.

in the csv I want it to come out:

---

### **|    Title     |      Sold_By     |    Sales_Perc   |   Time_Left   |**

### **| Title1 |       Amazon     |  10% Apartadas  |   06:05:12    |**

**| Title2 |       Amazon     |  18% Apartadas  |   08:55:11    |**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome('c:/bin/chromedriver')

lst=[]
for page_nb in range(1, 2):
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com.mx/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-5_2c3b_page_' + str(page_nb) + '?gb_f_c2xvdC01=dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL%252CEXPIRED%252CSOLDOUT,dealTypes:LIGHTNING_DEAL,page:' + str(page_nb) + ',sortOrder:BY_SCORE,dealsPerPage:48&pf_rd_p=d8b66f14-9e78-4a85-b04f-327a0b562c3b&pf_rd_s=slot-5&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=AVDBXBAVVSXLQ&pf_rd_r=5YBFC04YTSW7FDETY9RQ&ie=UTF8')
    sleep(2)
    for product_tree in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@id, "101_dealView_")]'):
        title = product_tree.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@id="dealTitle"]/span').text
        vendido = product_tree.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@id="shipSoldInfo"]').text
        apartado = product_tree.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="a-size-mini a-color-secondary inlineBlock unitLineHeight"]').text
        tventa = product_tree.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@role="timer"]').text
        lst.append([title, vendido, apartado, tventa])
        #print(title, vendido, apartado, tventa)

driver.close()

#exporting data into a csv file
import csv
header = ['Titulo', 'Sold_by', 'Sold_Perc', 'Time_left']
data = [title, vendido, apartado, tventa]

with open('Test.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(data)
    

print('Done...')
```

Comment: A csv is a file containing data separated by newlines and commas.  You don't need to ask such a  simple thing here, on stackoverflow.

Comment: Just toss my lst into your writer and your good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you put the wrong list into your writer. You save all scraping variable in **lst**, so remember to write **lst** in your csv.

```
import csv
header = ['Titulo', 'Sold_by', 'Sold_Perc', 'Time_left']

with open('Test.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(header)
    // replace data with lst
    writer.writerow(lst)
```